# Even after publishing the application in android market, the status shows unpublished

Tags: android

I just published an application in Android Market. It doesn't give any error message but when I go to my homepage and check application status it shows unpublished. Can anyone please let me know what the issue is?

Thanks
Akash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you usually have to wait a couple hours...

Comment: Thanks for your response DJPlayer.

Comment: It has been around 10 hours since I have published my application but it still shows the status as unpublished.

Comment: take a look at this thread.  Also you probably shouldn't be using the copy protection option.  It has taken people 24+hrs (only on occasion though).  http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=3bb960d59eba7d04&hl=en

Comment: Hi DJ.. I have not used the copy protection.Also following are the permissions required<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Also moreover when i sigh in in my developer account it shows the status unpublished. I think it is different from showing in the market.

Comment: I solved the issue... The issue was I was pressing publish button on the main page and not on the APK page. Just did that and problem solved. Thanks for your help

Comment: just a tip. After publishing try downloading yourself.. make sure everything works ok w/ downloading. Based on your permissions looks like it's a free app..b/c you don't have google pay permissions.  Oh an dyou want to click the answered button so you don't have unresolved questions.